# Alocando texto dinamicamente, e erro no free()

Tags: c, ponteiro, memória

Estou tentando alocar dinamicamente, porém está aparecendo o erro:

> Error in ./nome.c; invalid pointer : 0x0000000001c18834

Meu código:

```
// FUNCAO // 
char *nome(text[])  
{    
    int n3 = 0;  
    int n2 = 0;     
    char *n = NULL;  

    while((n2 = getchar()) != '\0' && n2 != EOF)  
    {  
        n3++;  
        n = realloc(n, n3*sizeof(char));  
        if(n == NULL)  
        {  
            puts("Erro ao realocar!");  
            exit(0);  
            free(n);  
        }   
        *(n+(n3-1)) = n2;   
    }  
    *(n+n3) = '\0';  
    return n;
}

// USANDO //   
int main(void)  
{  
    char *name = nome("Nome:");  
    while(*name != '\0')  
    printf("%c", *name++);    
    free(name); // aqui ta o problema, sem o free roda normal agora com o free me da esse erro
}
```

Comment: Esse código nem compila, tem erros de sintaxe, então fica complicado até falar alguma coisa. Mas experimentou usar `free(name)`. Não tem porque derreferenciá-lo.

Comment: nao sei editar o texto aqui da ultima vez alguem edito pra min

Comment: Para editar sua pergunta clique em [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/213845/edit).

Comment: testa ai alguem com o free e sem o free

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O código tem alguns problemas, inclusive não está legível. Simplifiquei um pouco. O problema mais sério mesmo é que guarda em `name` o ponteiro para o local alocado. Ele não pode ser modificado para que depois possa ser dado o `free` no local coreto. Quando o incrementa vai tentar liberar memória em lugar que não houve alocação e gera o erro. O correto é criar uma variável de iteração independente e ir incrementando ela, assim não mexe me `name`.

Não vi se tem outros problemas.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *nome(char text[]) {    
    int n3 = 0;
    int n2 = 0;
    char *n = NULL;
    while((n2 = getchar()) != '\0' && n2 != EOF) {
        n = realloc(n, ++n3);
        if (n == NULL) {
            puts("Erro ao realocar!");
            exit(0);
        }
        *(n + (n3 - 1)) = n2;   
    }
    *(n + n3) = '\0';  
    return n;
}   

int main(void) {  
    char *name = nome("Nome:");
    char *iterador = name;
    while(*iterador != '\0') printf("%c", *iterador++);
    printf("%s", name); //bem mais simples, certo?
    free(name);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/dzOKhS). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/czhzwwnm-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Pointer/PointerInteration.c).

Comment: deu certo usar o iterador vlw amigo, e sobre o codigo não está legível é porque eu não sei editar aqui no stackoverflow

Comment: Não, o problema não é esse, inclusive o meu ainda não está tão legível, porque não quis mexer demais no seu código. Note que usando o `printf()` nem precisaria do iterador.

Comment: eu nao copiei e colei eu escrevi tudo aqui

Comment: Primeiro não deveria ter feito isto, segundo, a ilegibilidade está ano código, não da digitação.

Comment: pode ser então que meu código não esteja legivel, vlw pelo toque vou tentar melhorar nesse aspecto, mais o código já esta rodando obrigado a todos que ajudarão