# Comando getchar() usado varias vezes

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    char c1, c2, c3;
    printf("Digite um caractere: \n");
    c1 = getchar();
    printf("Digite um caractere: \n");
    c2 = getchar();
    printf("Digite um caractere: \n");
    c3 = getchar();
    printf("Primeiro caractere: %c\nSegundo caractere: %c\nTerceiro caractere: %c\n", c1);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Esse código deveria ler 3 caracteres e usando apenas um printf, mostrar os caracteres na tela, no entanto esta fazendo a primeira leitura, gostaria de entender o porque e como corrigir. Valeu!

Exercicio: Faça um programa que leia três caracteres do tipo char e depois os imprima um em cada linha. Use um único comando printf() para isso.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seu problema acontece porque você não está familiarizado com a entrada do programa.
Quando você recebe algo como

```
a
b
c
```

na verdade seu programa lê como

```
a\nb\nc
```

e o seu programa acaba obtendo

```
c1 = 'a'
c2 = '\n'
c3 = 'b'
```

Para resolver isso, você pode adicionar getchars que servem apenas para remover os '\n' do caminho obtendo o seguinte código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    char c1, c2, c3;
    printf("Digite um caractere: \n");
    c1 = getchar();
    getchar(); //pega o primeiro '\n'
    printf("Digite um caractere: \n");
    c2 = getchar();
    getchar(); //pega o segundo '\n'
    printf("Digite um caractere: \n");
    c3 = getchar();
    printf("Primeiro caractere: %c\nSegundo caractere: %c\nTerceiro caractere: %c\n", c1, c2, c3);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Obs1: Vale notar que eu adicionei mais parâmetros no printf que estavam faltando

Obs2: Outra coisa que vale ressaltar é que, caso você esteja usando windows, normalmente a quebra de linha acontece através de dois caracteres, então seriam necessários dois getchars para cada quebra de linha na entrada

Answer (score 3):

Assim?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char c;
    printf("Digite um caractere:\n");
    char c1 = getchar();
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) { }
    printf("Digite um caractere:\n");
    char c2 = getchar();
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) { }
    printf("Digite um caractere:\n");
    char c3 = getchar();
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) { }
    printf("Primeiro caractere: %c\nSegundo caractere: %c\nTerceiro caractere: %c\n", c1, c2, c3);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/GCeHOn). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/rgmelwdt-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Console/PrintChars.c).

Só faltou mandar imprimir os outros dois, não basta ter intenção de mostrar tem que passar a variável com o valor para a impressão ser feita.

Simplifiquei um pouco também.

De fato o `getchar()` não funciona da forma que está esperando. Na verdade todo mecanismo de entrada de dados do C é confuso pela forma como ele gerencia o *buffer*. E tem muita gente que tenta soluções mágicas. Algumas funcionam só em certas situações mas como ela vê funcionando ela acha que é certo. Tá cheio na internet mostrando errado. Então o melhor é fazer o simples ou fazer uma função sua que funciona sempre do jeito que espera.

Eu fiz uma limpeza de *buffer* na mão que funciona sempre, ainda que seja feio.

De qualquer forma não sei se o intuito do exercício seria esse. Ele está dizendo que precisa ler os 3 caracteres separadamente? Não, então você pode fazer de outra forma. Ele só é específico em como deve imprimir. Assim funciona perfeitamente:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Digite três caracteres:\n");
    char chars[4];
    scanf("%3s", chars);
    printf("Primeiro caractere: %c\nSegundo caractere: %c\nTerceiro caractere: %c\n", chars[0], chars[1], chars[2]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/81Jvr4). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/kleehmsr-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Console/ScanChars.c).

Pode ler mais em [Como ler do stdin em C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42981/101). E [como usar o `getchar()` da forma correta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/213845/101) (sim, é confuso).

Comment: mas ai eu estaria usando um array, que estaria "fora das regras", já que o livro não havia ensinado ainda, entendi a sua solução mas não me satisfaz. Valeu

Comment: Não está, eu li na pergunta o que está escrito não tem nada falando sobre isso.